# HTML5 input text/password field pattern join by a number

Tags: regex, html, validation

In HTML5:

How could I validate my input text , by a regular expression that the chain has at least 1 number ?

I'm looking for is that you can write anything but at least have a chain number written

```
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" pattern="[0-9]+" required>
```

Thanks

Comment: What does "chain" mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

with javascript/jquery, e.g.

```
<input id="test"/>

$('#test').on('change',testme);
function testme(e) {

   if ( e.target.value.match(/[0-9]+/) ) {
       alert('yay!');
   }
}
```

for the pattern property:

```
<input class="span2" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" pattern=".*[0-9]+.*" required>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The expression you typed contains only numbers, what I'm looking for is that you can write anything but at least have a chain number written

Comment: this expression will match positive for abc1, 1abc, a1bc, 1, etc.: https://jsfiddle.net/5s4vhfkw/ but negatiive for abc or whatever. what is a 'chain number'? if a chain number is like 111 but not 121, then you can modify the regex like: /([0-9])\1+/ -- that'll hit on abc11 but not abc1 or abc12.

Comment: <input class="span2" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" pattern="/[0-9]+/" required> its not working

Comment: He's looking for a **pattern** to use in an HTML `input` element.

Comment: the original post did not include a lot of detail and though he indicated html5 in the title, I wasn't familiar with the pattern property at the time hence my JS suggestion (it is not uncommon for people to misspeak their needs). once the post was updated to indicate the pattern property was where the regex was needed, I amended my answer to include a pattern property solution (while leaving the JS solution in case it could be useful for folks not using HTML5).

Answer (score 1):

I think below code will help you to solve your problem

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="^\d{1,}$"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The expression you typed contains only numbers, what I'm looking for is that you can write anything but at least have a chain number written

Comment: You don't need `^` and `$` in the pattern specified in an input element. They're implied.

Comment: Upvoting to encourage you to keep contributing and fix your answer. By the way, instead of inventing your own sample `input` element, why don't you use the one provided by the OP?

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern=".*\d.*"
```

which means

> Any number of characters, then a digit, then any number of characters.